# Does data view(index pattern) is limited to 100 source?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I`m using Kibana to create data view for searching. I had noticed that there was a suggestion

> Your index pattern match 100 sources

[image]

Does that mean that the query scope of data view I created is limited to 100 sources? if I have sources more than 100, I would be missing some data when search

Answer (score 0):

Looks like yes, 100 is the hard limit for index patterns.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-create-index-pattern-if-you-have-more-than-100-indices/197919

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/index-pattern-is-limited-to-100/133463

Comment: not pretty sure ,i used profile api to show the underlying index is using, the count is over 100